# Create my own string function python

Tags: python, function

```
"this is my string".myfunction(argument)
```

This is very simple in javascript. With the keyword this i can access to my string directly. Is that possible with python?

Answer (score 1):

You can inherit from `str` and define your own methods:

```
class myString(str):
    def my_method(self, ...):
        # ...

some_string = myString("StackOverflow")

print some_string.count("a") # method from string
print some_string.myMethod(...) # your defined method
```

Comment: But i wouldn't like to declare each string as instance of a class. Does not exists more ways to do this?

Comment: Maybe you can just create a function that receives two parameters: `my_funcion(str1, str2)` It will be "similar" to `str1.my_function(str2)`

Comment: Yeah i think that is the only way to do it. But i wanted to extend the function join. Something like ",".join_reverse(list) but is not possible with this language.

Comment: You can always use `join()` in the new function you will create. I don't see the point of "extending" it.

Comment: Can i do this: `"my spliter".join_reverse(list)`
instead of `join_reverse("my spliter", list)` ?

Comment: @EnZo What's the benefit of doing that? It will work anyway.

Comment: homogeneity? flexibility?

Comment: Sometimes you have to sacrifice those things in order to achieve the *most important*, in this case the operation `join_reverse()`.

Comment: What do you mean with "in order to achieve the most important"?

Comment: The main goal is to make the operation of `join_reverse()`. In order to do that, you may have to sacrifice flexibility.

Comment: Right, but for me is not the only goal. For me is important write a good code, uniform and legible. That's why javascript is my favorite language at this moment. Because give me more flexibility than any other.

Comment: How is `join_reverse(str1, str2)` not a good code? Come on.

Comment: Could be, but this solution is more elegant `"string".join_reverse(list)`
because the original way is `"string".join(list)` is more understandable and consistent.
Also other option than give me javascript than python not, is extend the prototype. And i can do something like this:
`"string".join(list, reverse)`
Reverse is false as default.
Anyway, i am learning python and i was wondering if can do some things.
Thank you for your help.